# How to get id of a clicked hyperlink and post in another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

I have two pages, index.php and view.php . I take informations from an API. What i need is on clicked `<a>` tag in index to post the id of that `<a>` to $a variable in the other page. Should i use jquery?

index.php

```
<style>
table a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

</style>
<?php
$login = 'djfjshfjshsdhfsjfhdsjhsjfhsjhfdsjhs';

$url = 'https://api.recruiterbox.com/v1/openings';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:");

$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  




$data = json_decode($results);
$data1 = json_decode($results, true);


/*
var_dump($data);

*/




if (count($data->objects)) {


        // Open the table

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<th>Job Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Date updated</th>";

        // Cycle through the array
        $string = "noportal";$string1 = "noportal";
        foreach ($data->objects as $idx => $objects) {


            // Output a row
            if($objects->tags[0] !== $string) { 

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='view' id='$objects->id'>$objects->title</a></td>";

            echo "<td>".date('m/d/Y',$objects->created_on)."</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
            }
            else { }

        }

        // Close the table
        echo "</table>";
    }

?>
```

view.php

```
<style>
table a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

</style>
<?php
$login = '11sfsdfsdsfsfsfs';

$url1 = 'https://api.recruiterbox.com/v1/openings/';
$a ='mp06fne';
$url=$url1.$a;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:");

$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
$data = json_decode($results, true);

/*
var_dump($data);

*/

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Job Position:</td>";
echo "<td>".$data['title']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can you please paste your generated html and javascript code rather than the php code? It will be easier to answer

Comment: This is all i have got. I am confused now how to go on.

Comment: Php code is not gonna help, u Need to use Java, and then write in the Java script code somthing similar to: var id = $(this).val('Id);

Comment: why java? Html is something that is generated on client and javascript has access to all the dom elements. 
What moji said - to use $(this).val('id') makes sense but this is very much achievable from this PHP code and no need to move to Java for this

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for jQuery. The simplest solution would be to pass the value of the id using the GET.

In index.php, when you generate the link here:

```
echo "<td><a href='view' id='$objects->id'>$objects->title</a></td>"
```

Add the id of link in the `href` too. Something like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='view?id=$objects->id' id='$objects->id'>$objects->title</a></td>"
```

Then at the top of view.php, read the value of the parameter by using `$_GET`:

```
$link_clicked_id = isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : null;
```

now you will have the ID of the link clicked on the variable `$link_clicked_id`.